# Implementing google play services sign-in on android

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

I'm trying to implement google play services Sign-in by following this guide https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin but when the activity starts, I get this error:

`07-16 16:37:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(7732): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 16:37:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(7732): java.lang.IllegalStateException: A fatal developer error has occurred. Check the logs for further information.
07-16 16:37:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(7732):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.hc$h.b(Unknown Source)
07-16 16:37:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(7732):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.hc$h.d(Unknown Source)
07-16 16:37:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(7732):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.hc$b.fq(Unknown Source)
07-16 16:37:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(7732):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.hc$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
07-16 16:37:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(7732):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-16 16:37:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(7732):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-16 16:37:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(7732):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306)
07-16 16:37:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(7732):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-16 16:37:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(7732):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-16 16:37:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(7732):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
07-16 16:37:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(7732):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
07-16 16:37:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(7732):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

and this is the full code of the activity I'm trying to start:

public class Test extends BaseGameActivity implements OnClickListener{

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);
    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onSignInFailed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

@Override
public void onSignInSucceeded() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // show sign-out button, hide the sign-in button
    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (view.getId() == R.id.sign_in_button) {
        // start the asynchronous sign in flow
        beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
    }
    else if (view.getId() == R.id.sign_out_button) {
        // sign out.
        signOut();

        // show sign-in button, hide the sign-out button
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
public abstract class BaseGameActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    GameHelper.GameHelperListener {

    // The game helper object. This class is mainly a wrapper around this object.
    protected GameHelper mHelper;

    // We expose these constants here because we don't want users of this class
    // to have to know about GameHelper at all.
    public static final int CLIENT_GAMES = GameHelper.CLIENT_GAMES;
    public static final int CLIENT_APPSTATE = GameHelper.CLIENT_APPSTATE;
    public static final int CLIENT_PLUS = GameHelper.CLIENT_PLUS;
    public static final int CLIENT_ALL = GameHelper.CLIENT_ALL;

    // Requested clients. By default, that's just the games client.
    protected int mRequestedClients = CLIENT_GAMES;

    private final static String TAG = "BaseGameActivity";
    protected boolean mDebugLog = false;

    /** Constructs a BaseGameActivity with default client (GamesClient). */
    protected BaseGameActivity() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a BaseGameActivity with the requested clients.
     * @param requestedClients The requested clients (a combination of CLIENT_GAMES,
     *         CLIENT_PLUS and CLIENT_APPSTATE).
     */
    protected BaseGameActivity(int requestedClients) {
        super();
        setRequestedClients(requestedClients);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the requested clients. The preferred way to set the requested clients is
     * via the constructor, but this method is available if for some reason your code
     * cannot do this in the constructor. This must be called before onCreate or getGameHelper()
     * in order to have any effect. If called after onCreate()/getGameHelper(), this method
     * is a no-op.
     *
     * @param requestedClients A combination of the flags CLIENT_GAMES, CLIENT_PLUS
     *         and CLIENT_APPSTATE, or CLIENT_ALL to request all available clients.
     */
    protected void setRequestedClients(int requestedClients) {
        mRequestedClients = requestedClients;
    }

    public GameHelper getGameHelper() {
        if (mHelper == null) {
            mHelper = new GameHelper(this, mRequestedClients);
            mHelper.enableDebugLog(mDebugLog);
        }
        return mHelper;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);
        if (mHelper == null) {
            getGameHelper();
        }
        mHelper.setup(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mHelper.onStart(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mHelper.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int request, int response, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
        mHelper.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
    }

    protected GoogleApiClient getApiClient() {
        return mHelper.getApiClient();
    }

    protected boolean isSignedIn() {
        return mHelper.isSignedIn();
    }

    protected void beginUserInitiatedSignIn() {
        mHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
    }

    protected void signOut() {
        mHelper.signOut();
    }

    protected void showAlert(String message) {
        mHelper.makeSimpleDialog(message).show();
    }

    protected void showAlert(String title, String message) {
        mHelper.makeSimpleDialog(title, message).show();
    }

    protected void enableDebugLog(boolean enabled) {
        mDebugLog = true;
        if (mHelper != null) {
            mHelper.enableDebugLog(enabled);
        }
    }

    @Deprecated
    protected void enableDebugLog(boolean enabled, String tag) {
        Log.w(TAG, "BaseGameActivity.enabledDebugLog(bool,String) is " +
                "deprecated. Use enableDebugLog(boolean)");
        enableDebugLog(enabled);
    }

    protected String getInvitationId() {
        return mHelper.getInvitationId();
    }

    protected void reconnectClient() {
        mHelper.reconnectClient();
    }

    protected boolean hasSignInError() {
        return mHelper.hasSignInError();
    }

    protected GameHelper.SignInFailureReason getSignInError() {
        return mHelper.getSignInError();
    }


    }
```

}

Comment: Have you tried of checking `null` exception at `view` before using it?

Comment: You mean the view in the onClick method?

Comment: have you used all meta-data in your manifest

Comment: Yes I've used both Google Play Services Version and APP-ID meta-data, should I be using something else?

Answer (score 2):

if your package name or app_id is inavailability the err will be thrown!

when you want implement google play services,you must create a App in the google play,get the app_id and appoint a package name;
if it was ok, then you will change your app's package name is your own package name (the same one you registered in Developer Console) likes com.example.*.
and you will Modify your app_id in the res/values/ids.xml or other file;

you can get more help in 
https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples
the section "Modify IDs, compile and run" is very useful.

good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I've already done that and I've already red "Modify IDs, compile and run" section. I tried everything I don't know what to do anymore

Comment: oh~~ Yesterday,i find the app_id must include the xml file in the /res directory,if only write it in the AndroidManifest.xml,the err will thrown.
it seem that you must write this:

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
                   android:value="@string/app_id" />

in the AndroidManifest.xml and define a string app_id  in the res xml file

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the correct version of APP_ID in your manifest.

For clients accessing `GameHelper.CLIENT_APPSTATE` you need

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID"
           android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

For ones accessing `GameHelper.CLIENT_SNAPSHOT` you need

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" 
           android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

Save game snapshots is a new feature that is intended to replace appstate, but this error condition is easy to run in to while migrating from the one to the other.  Contrary to the exception stating that you should review the error logs, there is not actually a log entry showing any error prior to the exception being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the `BaseGameActivity` as an inner class. You should reference it from a library. [Follow this link and follow the steps 1-8 under "Setting up your game project"](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init)

EDIT:

Firstly, reference the **BaseGameUtils** library in your project.

Now look at this code:

```
import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.BaseGameActivity;

public class Test extends BaseGameActivity { //contained in the library
    // override unimplemented methods here.
}
```

That's all you really need.

Comment: But it also says that you have to subclass the main Activity in your game from the BaseGameActivity class

Comment: @Mantech Yeah you have already done that. Your class is called **Test** and it extends **BaseGameActivity**. BaseGameActivity is not supposed to be defined by you. You are supposed to reference the library in your project and then say `import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.BaseGameActivity;` and then just extend it from your main class and that's it. Please see my edit.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried everything also this solution but I always get the same error, maybe it has something to do with App-ID and stuff like that?

Comment: @Mantech You know how it says **a fatal developer error has occurred, check the logs**. Go through your logcat and look for red messages. There should be something there that tells you what the error actually is. Eg, Games services misconfigured! Or something like that.

Comment: All the errors line of the logcat are here, and as you can see the error is not that clear. It could be Games Service misconfigured, but in that case I don't know how to find a solution since I did exactly what the google guide says.